# How to check given point is in between two non linear lines in C#?

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have multiple points[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] which draws a plus error line and there are other set of points for min error line.

I want to check the given point (X1, Y1) is resides in between plus and min error line or not in c#.
[image]

Comment: A finite set of points does not form a line. Are you assuming that straight lines join all the points together?

Comment: @Sweeper I have 150 points for each line(3 lines are there) which draws lines as like screenshot and those are not straight lines. for example in the screenshot. the given point doesn't lies in between 2(plus and min error) lines.

Comment: Let me put this another way, a mathematical line cannot be formed by a finite number of points. The many points you have may *look* like a "line", but it isn't. For example, how is the "line" defined between the first point and the second point you have? Does it go to some random direction, before joining the second point? Or do you assume there is a straight line that joins the first and second point, and another straight line that joins the second and third point together, and so on?

Comment: For starting points and ending points of line we can consider straight line will join points together.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for clarifying the question. Yes, straight line between two points joins successive points.

Comment: How non-linear?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou there are multiple points and by joining all then line is non-linear. but. the line between two successive point is considered as linear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the that straight lines join successive points, and the max and min lines' points have the same X coordinates, there are only 4 points that matter for every input point.

It is the two points on each line that have X coordinates just below and just above the target point's X coordinate, i.e. the points that are closest to the target point in terms of X coordinate.

Assuming the points of the two lines are sorted by X coordinates, you just need to find the first point that exceeds the target point's X coordinate, and the point before that, for each line.

```
// can probably use binary search to make this faster if you use lists instead,
// but that's left as an exercise for the reader :)
(Point, Point)? RelevantPoints(Point point, IEnumerable<Point> line) {
    using var enumerator = line.GetEnumerator();
    Point? previous = null;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        if (previous == null) {
            previous = current;
            continue;
        }

        // when we "go past" the target point's X coordinate
        if (current.X >= point.X) {
            return (previous.Value, current);
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then we can construct a linear equation from the two points. A method that returns the Y coordinate on the line, when given an X coordinate.

```
float LineEquation(Point p1, Point p2, float x) =>
    (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X) * (x - p1.X) + p1.Y;
```

Assuming the two lines does not intersect (for every X coordinate, the "max" line is always above the "min" line), you can then check the Y coordinates of the lines at the X coordinate of the target point.

```
bool IsBetweenTwoLines(Point point, IEnumerable<Point> maxLine, IEnumerable<Point> minLine) {
    if (RelevantPoints(point, maxLine) is var (maxLeft, maxRight) && 
        RelevantPoints(point, minLine) is var (minLeft, minRight)) {
        // assuming points on the line are considered "in between",
        // which is why I'm using <= and >= rather than < and >
        return point.Y <= LineEquation(maxLeft, maxRight, point.X) &&
            point.Y >= LineEquation(minLeft, minRight, point.X);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In the ReleventPoints method, As the condition if (previous == null) continue; is there it will never execute the below code.

Comment: @H_H thanks. `previous` should be assigned first, and then continue.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps simple approach is suitable for your purposes:

For given point `X1,Y1` find the closest `x[k]` coordinate (use linear or binary search over point array), so `x[k] <= X1`, get also next `x[k+1]` coordinate. So you have small straight line segment.

[image]

Calculate interpolated Y-coordinate at this line segment:

```
YYY = Y1 + (X1-x[k])*(y[k+1]-y[k])/(x[k+1]-x[k])
```

and compare absolute difference of Y1 and YYY with your "error
tolerance"

Answer (score 1):

So a little bit of geometry first.

Take any two consecutive points from your list to form a directed line, and check if your target point falls within the "inside" region. This means above from the min lines and below for the max lines.

If the point has at least **one** pair of lines (one for the min and one for the max) that meets these criteria then it lies within the bounds.

But how do be check for this?

#### Geometry

First the basic problem definition. Consider two points **A** and **B** that form the directed line **AB** with length *AB*. Now consider the target point **P** that you want to check where it lies with respect to this line

[image: fig1]

There are 6 possibilities. Three are to the left of the line (above the line in the sketch) and three are to the right of the line (below the line in the sketch). The three regions along the line are, before **A**, between **A** and **B** and after **B**.

We consider the perpendicular projection of **P** onto the line as point **Q** and measure the distance *AQ* to find a dimensionless quantity **w** which is defined as

```
w = AQ/AB
```

[image: fig2]

If **w**<0 then **Q** is before **A**, if **w**>1 then **Q** is after **B** and otherwise if 0<**w**<1 then **Q** is between **A** and **B**.

Now to find which side of the line **P** is at. Consider the line as force, and check to see what kind of torque **τ** it produces about **P**. If this torque is positive **τ>0** then the point is to the left of the line, and if it is negative **τ<0*8 then the point is to the right of the line. If the torque is zero then it lies on the line.

#### Code

And here is some code. Look at `IsTargetPointInside()` which checks that there is at least one point in the correct region for the min line and the max line by checking all the combinations.

```
    public static class Geometry
    {
        public static float GetSideOfTargetPoint(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, Vector2 P)
        {
            float AB = Vector2.Distance(A, B);
            float τ = P.X * (A.Y - B.Y) + P.Y * (B.X - A.X) + A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X;
            return τ / AB;
        }
        public static Vector2 ProjectPoint(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, Vector2 P)
        {
            float num = Vector2.Dot(P - A, B - A);
            float den = Vector2.Dot(B - A, B - A);
            float w = num / den;
            return A + w * (B - A);
        }
        public static float GetBaryCoordinate(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, Vector2 P)
        {
            Vector2 Q = ProjectPoint(A, B, P);
            float num = Vector2.Distance(A, Q);
            float den = Vector2.Distance(A, B);
            return num / den;
        }

        public static bool IsTargetPointInside(Vector2 target, Vector2[] minLine, Vector2[] maxLine)
        {
            // assume points go from left to right
            int n = minLine.Length - 1, m = maxLine.Length - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Vector2 Amin = minLine[i], Bmin = minLine[i + 1];

                float τ_min = GetSideOfTargetPoint(Amin, Bmin, target);
                if (τ_min < 0)
                {
                    // point is below min line
                    continue;
                }

                float w_min = GetBaryCoordinate(Amin, Bmin, target);
                if (w_min < 0 || w_min > 1)
                {
                    // point is before or after line-ends
                    continue;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Vector2 Amax = maxLine[j], Bmax = maxLine[j + 1];
                    float τ_max = GetSideOfTargetPoint(Amax, Bmax, target);
                    if (τ_max > 0)
                    {
                        // point is above max line
                        continue;
                    }

                    float w_max = GetBaryCoordinate(Amax, Bmax, target);
                    if (w_max < 0 || w_max > 1)
                    {
                        // point is before or after line-ends
                        continue;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

#### Test Cases

I run a few test cases and it seems to work

```text
Bounds.
     X (min)      Y (min)  |       X (max)      Y (max)
           1            1  |             1            3
           2          1.5  |             2          3.3
           3          1.8  |             3          3.4

Test Cases.
NO - Origin is not inside the bounds.
YES - (1.5, 2.5) is inside the bounds.
YES - (2.0, 2.5) is inside the bounds.
YES - (2.5, 2.5) is inside the bounds.
NO - (2.5, 3.4) is not inside the bounds.
NO - (3.0, 3.4) is not inside the bounds.
```

and the code for the test cases:

```c#
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckGeometry();
        }

        public static void CheckGeometry()
        {
            Vector2[] minLine = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(1, 1f),
                new Vector2(2, 1.5f),
                new Vector2(3, 1.8f),
            };
            Vector2[] maxLine = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(1, 3f),
                new Vector2(2, 3.3f),
                new Vector2(3, 3.4f),
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Bounds.");
            Console.WriteLine($"{"X (min)",12} {"Y (min)",12}  |  {"X (max)",12} {"Y (max)",12}");
            for (int index = 0; index < minLine.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{minLine[index].X,12} {minLine[index].Y,12}  |  {maxLine[index].X,12} {maxLine[index].Y,12}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Test Cases.");
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(0, 0), minLine, maxLine) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO - Origin is not inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(1.5f, 2.5f), minLine, maxLine) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES - (1.5, 2.5) is inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(2.0f, 2.5f), minLine, maxLine) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES - (2.0, 2.5) is inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(2.5f, 2.5f), minLine, maxLine) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES - (2.5, 2.5) is inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(2.5f, 3.4f), minLine, maxLine) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO - (2.5, 3.4) is not inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
            if (Geometry.IsTargetPointInside(new Vector2(3.0f, 3.4f), minLine, maxLine) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO - (3.0, 3.4) is not inside the bounds.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If X1 is not among the known xi, you need some interpolation method to estimate the Y- and Y+ corresponding to X1. If your points are dense enough (which seems to apply to your case), a linear interpolation is good enough. Then follow MBo's answer.

For less dense points, I would recommend a cubic spline or a chordal Hermite spline interpolant (easier to code).

---

If the curve that you show is a typical case (very smooth) and your accuracy requirement is "normal", you can probably do with a very low degree Lagrangian interpolant. For instance, just taking the two extreme points and another in the middle will give a good interpolating parabola.

Parabolic interpolation:

[image]